# Wifly Library that works with RN171

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, shields

Does anyone know of a library that works with the WiFly-RN171?
I've tried all that I could find (WiFly, WiFlyHQ and WiFlySerial) but none of them work.

WiFly and WiFlySerial both hang on WiFly.begin().

WiFlyHQ fails to enter command mode and hence proceeds no further.

I'm using the WiFly-RN171 with an Arduino Uno and Communication Shield (XBee, Bluetooth, RFID) - XBee Shield as seen below.

Has anybody gotten this configuration to work?

[image: arduino setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same configuration and it works (Arduino UNO rev3)
I used WiFlyHQ library. Just be carefull with the serial.

```
Serial.begin(9600);
...
if (!wifly.begin(&Serial, NULL)) { 
   ...
```

Upload with serial select then put it on USB and then open the monitor.